# Virtual Machine Scale Sets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a test azure subscription, I have created a Virtual Machine Scale Sets.

There are no errors in the scale set.

How do I connect to VM's and make my server to put in a load?

Can I connect with RDP to my Scale set VM's ? is this allowed?

Comment: Are you via Azure portal Marketplace to create the VMSS?

Answer (score 2):

If you create VMSS via Azure portal Marketplace, we **can't** add inbound NAT rules to use RDP to login the VMSS instances, we can't RDP them directly.
So if you want to login those instances, we can create a new VM in the **same Vnet**(same Vnet can connect by the private IP address), and use the private IP to RDP.
[image]

> How do I connect to VM's and make my server to put in a load?

By default, we can use load balancer public IP address and NAT port to RDP VMs behind the VMss.

> Can I connect with RDP to my Scale set VM's ? is this allowed?

You can create a windows VM in the same Virtual Network, this VM work as a **jumpbox**, then use this vm to RDP those instances via private IP address.

Another way, modify template to add NAT rules.

More information about VMss and NAT rules, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.